# Execution of worksheet subroutine upon creation of workbook from a template

Tags: excel, vba, addition, worksheet

I would like to know, please, if it is possible to write a function which would be contained within a workbook template, specifically within a particular worksheet that would be executed upon creation of that workbook via the *Workbooks.Add("template.xlsm")* method. Just as importantly the routine would **only** be executed upon creation.

In addition I would need to pass a set of parameters to the said funtion when performing the Add. Is that possible?

If not, it appears that I would have to either call the function (Application.Run) immediately after adding the workbook (now part of another project) or manipulate the contents of the new sheet directly which would not be as elegant IMHO.

Any help or suggestions would be gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

If the function will *only be executed at the time of creation*, then why does it need to be contained within the new workbook?

What's wrong with simply doing the following:

```
Sub New_Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add("template.xlsm")
    ' Execute your code here. It will only be called on creation
End Sub
```

Perhaps your question wasn't clear as to why the code needs to be contained within the new workbook if it's never going to be run again. If you do need to copy code into a module of the new workbook, then you can use VBA Extensibility; or alternatively add a reference to the new workbook to a code add-in.

Comment: In answer to your questions I did start by trying your suggestion of executing code to alter the workbook (please refer to my penultimate paragraph). I accept that this would be acceptable. So I don't consider this to be an unresolvable issue. My thinking is that it is best to try to keep code as local to the sheet or workbook in question as much as possible (you may regard that as wrong). With regard to your last points, Ive not heard of VBA Extensibility and furthermore don't know what you mean by adding a reference  to a code add-in. Thank you.